# How to show meta_values from specific posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried this code:

```
<select name="productSize" id="productSize">
    <?php
        $metakey = 'size';
        $sizes = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
        if ($sizes) {
            foreach ($sizes as $size) {
                echo "<option value=\"" . $size . "\">" . $size . "</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

But it shows all values with 'size' key from all posts. I want to show only the values which associated on each posts. How to do that?

Thank you, really appreciate your help.

Comment: I assume you have the post ID (eg you're calling this in the loop)?  I think you have two options.  Use the [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function, or change the SQL you're using to pass in the post ID.  Using `get_post_meta` is probably simpler.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I finally figure it by myself. Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: Well that makes your question utterly useless to the Stackoverflow community, doesn't it? You figured it out but couldn't be bothered to explain how you did it, so now nobody can benefit from it in the future.  Have the decency to write your solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Alter $post->ID if required, but by default it will load the current loaded post ID.

```
<select name="productSize" id="productSize">
    <?php
        global $post;
        $metakey = 'size';
        $sizes = get_post_meta($post->ID, $metakey, false);
        if (count($sizes) != 0) {
            foreach ($sizes as $size) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $size . "\">" . $size . "</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```